# Switching to Parent Frame from iFrame and finding an element in Parent frame using Selenium Webdriver. C#

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium, switching

Scenario:
- I have a page with an iFrame Text Editor and a button in the page too.
- I switched from the parent frame to the iFrame to read from the Text Editor body
- After reading from the body of the Text Editor, I want to click on the button in the parent frame of the page.
- For this I tried to switch back to the parent frame from the iFrame using the following statement:
webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
- But still I am not able to find the button element which resides in the parent frame.

I appreciate your help!
Thanks

Comment: Can we see the HTML of the IFrames

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys. It is solved!

The solution:

- When I had used the `webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` it switched the `webDriver` to the top most window of the page. [Previously I was looking for the button element in this window and therefore was not able to find it as the button was sitting in the main frame of the page]
- After switching to the main window, I switched the `webDriver` again to the main frame of the page. This main frame had the button element. Thus I was able to find the button element. And this solved the issue!

So the final code doesn't have `webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` but has the following in its place:

```
    _webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
    _webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame("mainFrame");
```

Note: `windowHandle` in the above code is the handle of the top most window of the page. I guess its value may change according to the browsers, not sure though.

Answer (score 11):

The following code worked fine:

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with a similar problem and found that I could switch back by `Window Handle`:

```
string currentWindow = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
// switch to frame and do stuff..
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow); // switch back
```